# Error while redirect to path after user sign in using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing a ruby on rails app and i want the user to redirect to specific pages after successful sign in with devise. I have the following code in my devise sessions controller:

```
protected
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.role == "User"
  redirect_to user_home_path
 else
  redirect_to org_home_path
 end
end
```

I have set up the controllers to display the page based on the redirect. However, the following error shows up after the sign in:

```
 AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Webs::SessionsController#create

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you  may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that      neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

I have searched, but with no luck. Please Help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`after_sign_in_path_for` should just return the path but not perform a redirect, try changing your method like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if resource.role == "User"
  user_home_path
 else
  org_home_path
 end
end
```